# vuetify combobox not updating its model on certain keypress

Tags: combobox, vuetify.js

I have added a combobox and when the user inputs something and then hits tab, enter, space, blur etc I want to call a method to do stuff with the updated v-model for the combobox.

The strange thing is that it is *only* when I hit tab that the model is actually updated with the input text. For any of the other keypress:es that I've assigned the method gets called but the v-model does not contain the input text.

Example, I input "text1" in the combobox and press tab. The method gets called and I see that param "mccmtoChips" contains "text1" as an item in an array.

I now input "text2" and press space. The method gets called but "mccmtoChips" only contains one item, "text1". I then press tab and the method gets called again. Now, "mccmtoChips" contains two items in an array, "text1" and "text2".

Why aren't any of the other keypress events containing the updated v-model? I'm using vuetify 2.1.12.

```
<v-combobox    
 multiple 
 chips 
 deletable-chips 
 append-icon 
 full-width 
 small-chips 
 hide-details 
 label="Usernames"
 v-model="mccmtoChips"                                        
 @keyup.tab="addMccmChip" 
 @keyup.enter="addMccmChip"
 @keyup.space="addMccmChip"
 @blur="addMccmChip()"
 @keyup.delete="removeMccmChip"
 @keyup.backspace="removeMccmChip"
 :loading="mccmUsernamesLoading"
 >
```